# Any T4 Editor for VS 2010 Beta 1?

Tags: visual-studio, t4, visual-studio-2010

VS2010 Beta 1 was released today, and I see lots of T4 usage in Entity Framework and modelling. Is there already a T4 Editor available?

Answer (score 1):

tangible T4 editor is available for VS2010 Beta 1 - includes intelli-sense and highlighting.
http://tangibleengineering.blogspot.com/2009/05/tangible-t4-editor-for-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

And tangible T4 Editor is now also available for VS 2010 RTM 
http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com

Answer (score 0):

[Tangible T4 Editor](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html) is quite popular.
You can find the free edition in [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/60297607-5fd4-4da4-97e1-3715e90c1a23)

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2010 Beta1 plus tangible T4 Editor rock.

Answer (score -1):

tangible T4 editor is also available for VS2010 RC now.
http://tangibleengineering.blogspot.com/2009/05/tangible-t4-editor-for-visual-studio.html